# Replacing multiple values within a pandas dataframe cell - python

Tags: python, pandas, cell

My problem: I have a pandas dataframe and one column in particular which I need to process contains values separated by (":") **and in some cases, some of those values between ":" can be value = value, and can appear at the start/middle/end of the string.** The length of the string can differ in each cell as we iterate through the row, for e.g.

```
clickstream['events']  
1:3:5:7=23  
23=1:5:1:5:3  
9:0:8:6=5:65:3:44:56  
1:3:5:4
```

I have a file which contains the lookup values of these numbers,e.g.

```
event_no,description,event
1,xxxxxx,login
3,ffffff,logout
5,eeeeee,button_click
7,tttttt,interaction
23,ferfef,click1
```

output required:

```
clickstream['events']  
login:logout:button_click:interaction=23
click1=1:button_click:login:button_click:logout
```

Is there a pythonic way of looking up these individual values and replacing with the `event` column corresponding to the `event_no` row as shown in the output? I have hundreds of events and trying to work out a smart way of doing this. `pd.merge` would have done the trick if I had a single value, but I'm struggling to work out how I can work across the values and **ignore the "=value" part of the string**

Answer (score 1):

Edit for to ignore missing keys in Dict:

```
import pandas as pd

EventsDict = {1:'1:3:5:7',2:'23:45:1:5:3',39:'0:8:46:65:3:44:56',4:'1:3:5:4'}
clickstream = pd.Series(EventsDict)
#Keep this as a dictionary
EventsLookup = {1:'login',3:'logout',5:'button_click',7:'interaction'}

def EventLookup(x):
    list1 = [EventsLookup.get(int(item),'Missing') for item in x.split(':')]
    return ":".join(list1)

clickstream.apply(EventLookup)
```

Since you are using a full DF and not just a series, use:

```
clickstream['events'].apply(EventLookup)
Output:
1                 login:logout:button_click:interaction
2             Missing:Missing:login:button_click:logout
4                     login:logout:button_click:Missing
39    Missing:Missing:Missing:Missing:logout:Missing...
```

Comment: Hi @Liam Foley - Thanks for answering. I have tried to replicate the above but seem to get the following error `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", u'occurred at index 1')`. The only change to your recreate statements was to have `clickstream = pd.DataFrame(EventsDict)` as `clickstream = pd.DataFrame([EventsDict])` to avoid the error `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index`.... any ideas? thanks

Comment: @Maruhk Sounds like the apply isn't working.  Can you post the exact code you have?  If you're using a full dataframe, you would have to do something like:  DF['COL'] = DF['COL'].apply(lambda x: .......

Comment: seems like my lookup dictionary was not created properly but following your method I replicated the transformation and ran the function but seem to get an error on the first value in the clickstream dataset. I have copied the code in the following location [ClickStream - Code & Output Error Link](http://pastebin.com/jmxsK3fh) - thanks

Comment: You make the dict, but then turn the object back into a series right away.

     eventlookup = eventlookup.set_index('no')['value'].to_dict()
     eventlookup = pd.Series(eventlookup)

Don't do the second part.   eventlookup = pd.Series(eventlookup).
What does the Dict look like?

Comment: Great, it's a dictionary now, which it needs to be.

Try the other part now.

clickstream['events'] = clickstream['events'].apply(lambda x: ":".join([eventlookup[str(item)] for item in x.split(':')]))

If that doesn't work, check to see if you your dictionary keys are strings or ints.  your dict keys datatype needs to match the datatype in clickstream['events'].  They all need to be either ints or strs.

Comment: thank you so much for guiding me in getting this problem solved. I'm nearly there - It works fine with all the known values in the lookup data but seems to fail if the corresponding value for the event is not present in the lookup table. I am going to see if I can embed an if statement within lambda to overcome this, something like this `clickstream['events']= clickstream['events'].apply(lambda x: ":".join([eventlookup[int(item)] if eventlookup[int(item)] in x.split(':') else x]))` I'll keep you in the loop. Thanks once again

Comment: No problem.

Try using dict.get() with default of 'missing' or whatever you want to call it.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError

Comment: @Maruhk  any luck yet?  Feel free to email me (address is in my profile).

Comment: unfortunately not - I'm stuck. I've just found additional entries in my Dataframe column which is causing issues which I didn't mention in my original question. The solution you provided works perfect as long as the events data is consistent with lookup data as per my original question, but trying to ignore values string where "=value" appears. I can't seem to find your email add? cheers!

Comment: @Maruhk just updated to ignore missing keys.  My email is in my Stackoverflow profile:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/2317751/liam-foley

Comment: thanks. The edit you have made treats everything between ":" as a string so for entries like **: 204=34:** will be classed as missing, even though I would have *204* in my lookup. In instances where **"="** pops up I would want the output to be something like this **"shoppingCart=34"**, and if that value does not exist then missing as you have defined. I've just run your function on some sample data and seem to get missing for everything.. [sample code](http://pastebin.com/EWfFPmce)